# Dict as a local variable in a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have the next code:

```
class PythagoreanProof(Scene):
    CONFIG={
    "color_triangulos":YELLOW,
    "color_rect_c":RED,
    "color_rect_b":ORANGE,
    "color_rect_a":ORANGE,
    "color_cuadrado_c":ORANGE,
    "opacidad_triangulos":0.6,
    "opacidad_cuadradro_a":0.6,
    "opacidad_cuadradro_b":0.6,
    "opacidad_cuadradro_c":0.6,
    "grosor_lineas":1,
    "l_a":5/5,
    "l_b":12/5,
    "l_c":13/5,
    }
    def construct(self):
        self.wait()
        self.pre_cuadrado()
        self.pos_cuadrado()
        self.tran_pre_pos_cuadrado()
        self.wait()

    def pre_cuadrado(self):
        cuadro=Square(side_length=self.l_a+self.l_b)
```

As you can see, I can access the key "l_a" through `self.l_a`

But in this much simpler code I get the following error

```
class Example():
     CONFIG = {'spam':25}

     def __init__(self, value):
         self.data = value 

         def display(self):
             print(self.data, self.spam)  

x=Example(2)
x.display()

AttributeError: 'Example' object has no attribute 'spam'
```

Why does it work in the first example? How does it actually work?

Thanks!

Comment: There must be something in the `Scene` class that makes it translate `self.XXX` to `self.CONFIG[XXX]` Your second class doesn't inherit from `Scene` so it doesn't do that.

Comment: Note, that dict isn't local, it is a class-level variable (not an instance variable). Well, to be pedantic, it is local to the class body scope during the execution of the class definition statement, but that scope ceases to exist after the statement is executed

Comment: @Barmar But I've seen in other modules, Dicts as class-level variable is modified as user wish.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @JuanSebastianGarciaPerez We can only speculate, there are various ways that could be happening (as your second piece of code demonstrates, it doesn't happen by default). It is certainly a result of something inherited: `class PythagoreanProof(Scene):` you would have to provide a [mcve] or, again, there can only be speculation and this isn't on-topic as formulated.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga how can I create a function to make the keys of CONFIG attributes?

Comment: `self.__dict__.update(self.CONFIG)`.

Answer (score 0):

As for why is works when `Scene` is inherited to the class `PythagoreanProof` you need to have a look at the code of `Scene` to see what it is actually doing.

In the class `Example` you have defined `CONFIG` as a class level object. Your method `display` needs to point to this object with `self.CONFIG` and then use the key 'spam' to get its value '25'.

In order ro make the keys in CONFIG attributes you can use the `@poperty` wrapper.

See the example below

```
class Example():
    CONFIG = {'spam': 25}

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.data = value

    def display(self):
        print(self.data, self.CONFIG['spam'])

    @property
    def spam(self):
        return self.CONFIG['spam']

x = Example(2)
x.display()
print(x.spam)
```

```
2 25
25
```

Note some of you idents are incorrect. Method `display` should not be a function under `__init__` but a method under class `Example`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there's some magic in the `Scene` class that plays with the `__getattr__` method. Like this :

```
class Scene:
    # Minimalistic example.
    # See https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self.CONFIG[name]


class Example(Scene):
    CONFIG = {'spam': 25}

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.data = value

    def display(self):
        print(self.data, self.spam)


x = Example(2)
x.display()
# -> 2 25
```